# Why request params is always NULL for PUT method in tomcat deployed in heroku

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, heroku, tomcat8

Whereas it is working fine for POST and DELETE methods.
The same war is working for all HTTP methods in local installed tomcat. 
As checked with heroku docs, there is no configuration is related to this issue.

If it is due to parseBodyMethods, then we can have no control over tomcat config. We can make changes only in our war file.

Used tomcat version : Tomcat 8

Answer (score 0):

Your http contentType is xmlurlencoded?

Comment: HTTP Content-Type header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: tomcat may decode http post body when it's contentType is form-urlencoded and method is POST, see https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html

Comment: You could change the params parseBodyMethods

Comment: Yes we can. But it is possible if we have control over server.xml. In heroku deployment we can deploy a war file but there is no control over tomcat configuration.